# IOS: problem with an NSMutableArray 

Tags: cocoa-touch, exception, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have this code;

```
for (int i = 0; i<period+1; i++){

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *newData = [dataToAdd dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*j];
    j++;
    NSString *data = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newData];
    [[appDelegate.globalArray objectAtIndex:[name intValue]]addObject:data];

    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

this code work fine until I go in background.
appDelegate.globalArray is a global array and when I go in background I store it with NSUserDefault

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

globalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"globalArray"]];}
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:globalArray forKey:@"globalArray"];}
```

the loop work fine until I go in background but when I reopen the application and I enter in this loop I have an exception

"NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object"

why?

Comment: Could you please let us know the declaration of "globalArray" to check  if it is declared as NSArray instead of NSMutableArray?

Comment: it's declared as NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `globalArray`an array of arrays? If so, then you need to ensure that each array in `globalArray` is an instance of `NSMutableArray`as well. I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that when you get an array back from `NSUserDefaults`, you always get an *immutable* array. The same goes for your nested arrays.

In that case, you could try the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"globalArray"]];
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[temp count]];

    for (NSArray *nestedArray in temp) {
        [result addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nestedArray]];
    }

    // assuming globalArray is a @property retained by your class
    self.globalArray = result;

    [result release];
    [temp release];
}
```

There may be a more efficient way to do this, but you get my point...

Comment: ok but can I do this inside the method where is my loop or I must write this code in applicationDidBecomeActive?

Comment: The intention was to do this in the `-applicationDidBecomeActive` method only, and have this code execute only once per app launch.

Comment: but so in my loop what I must change? (loop in my first post)

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that you are trying to use *insertObject:* in a immutable array, because once you add the array to the global it gone immutable.

Comment: I know, so I'm trying to use a mutablecopy

Comment: Why don't you copy to a new mutable array, change it, and then send it back?

Comment: can you show me an example?, because I don't know Where I should create mutable copy...

Comment: you didn't show the code where you do the **insertObject:** so i cant do a example for your code, what i was suggesting is just when you need manipulate the content of the global array, copy it to a new auxiliary mutable array.

Comment: ok but where I must create this auxiliary array? first of the loop?

Comment: I can create a new array that I call globalArrayTemp and I do appDelegate.globalArrayTemp = [appDelegate.globalArray mutableCopy], it's right?